How can I remove this fan mount bracket?
As you can hopefully see from the picture, one of the screw studs is all mangled and doesn't accept a screw. How do I remove this so I can put in a new one? I was under the impression you just twist it to unscrew from in between the joists, but I can't seem to get it to twist. Any help would be much appreciated.


It should be screwed(maybe nailed) to the joists.  It might be the screw hole studs are replaceable and they might twist/turn off.  You should check the top side and see if a nut is there.

Slide your cell phone up there and take a video or a bunch of pictures so you know exactly what you're dealing with.

This is on the first floor of a two story house so there is no access from above. How do I get the old one out in order to use an old work replacement? Is it a case of having to cut and patch drywall in order to gain access?

From the image, it appears the stud might be riveted, i.e., the end above the plate is peened over. The question is how to replace it if you do not have access from above.
The simplest option, if the stud can be removed, is to fit a bolt just a trifle longer than the stud from above, locking it in place with a nut.

First, try grabbing the stud with locking pliers and rocking gently back and forth and side to side. If the stud moves, and if the plate above does not bend, then it should break loose.
If that fails, use a cut-off blade on a high-speed rotary tool to sever the stud as close to the plate as feasible,
In either case, drill out the remains of the stud so that the hole is large enough to sneak a bolt in from above, then add a nut to lock it in place.
If it's impossible to tip a bolt through the hole, cut the head off the bolt, put a nut atop the plate and start one on the bolt, and push the bolt up from below.

N.B.
The bolt and nut will be continually vibrated by the fan. Use high-strength hardware and use lock nuts and/or adhesive, such as Loctite Threadlocker (references are examples only).

Those aren't studs, they're internally threaded rods.  I doubt they are replaceable or even removable—at least not from below.  And if you're able to remove this bracket, there's not need to fool with the threads—you'll simply replace the bracket, ideally with a proper box.
Although the tip of the one is mangled, it's possible that you can still use it.  It will require cutting or grinding off the mangled part and re-tapping the new tip (just from the cutting burrs).  You may need a longer fastener (see Pippik reply above).
But I would not use this bracket for a fan, unless you can confirm the strength of the bracket, i.e. how it ties into adjacent joists.
